# MySQL inner join group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have 4 MySQL Tables shown here:**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6efe/2/0)**

I need to select station name, brand, fuel_type and fual_price for each station in given set and fuel typ in given set, e.q all Shell stations with fuel Diesel and Natural.

I would like to have all data related to one station in one row, which means I have e.g. 5 fuel types/prices for 1 station.

Example output -

```
id | name     | brand | fuel-data
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | Brzotice | Shell | Natural95-37.9, Diesel Power-45.8
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will give you want you want:

```
select s.id, 
  s.name,
  b.brand,
  group_concat(concat(f.type, '-', fs.price)) Fuel_Data
from sam_fuel f
left join sam_station_fuel fs
  on f.id = fs.id_fuel
left join sam_station s
  on fs.id_station = s.id
left join sam_station_brand b
  on s.brand = b.id
group by s.id, s.name, b.brand
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6efe/18)

Basically this query [joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) all of your tables.  Then to get the `fuel_data` field it applies both the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) functions

Comment: thank you, I did not know how to write group concat